# Replicating a record in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which looks like the following.

```
ID DATE1     DATE2      DATE3      DATE4  
1  01/01/17  02/01/17   03/01/17   04/01/17
```

Now I want to create a new table after selecting from this table which will look like the following

```
ID DATE  
1  01/01/17  
1  02/01/17  
1  03/01/17  
1  04/01/17
```

Please help me on building the query.

Comment: Check out `UNPIVOT`.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @SrikanthA, you can `CREATE TABLE T ("DATE" DATE);` - but really not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is often just `union all`:

```
SELECT ID, DATE1 as date FROM t UNION ALL
SELECT ID, DATE2 as date FROM t UNION ALL
SELECT ID, DATE3 as date FROM t UNION ALL
SELECT ID, DATE4 as date FROM t;
```

If you have a really large table, then this scans the table multiple times.  There are alternatives, if performance is a potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read about UNPIVOT. Giving you a solution and you copying the answer will keep you unaware of this brilliant concept in SQL.

> https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1